# |Ubuntu 18.04, opencv-3.4.0, MATLAB/R2018a| make fails on undefined reference to cv::dnn::eperimental

Tags: matlab, opencv, build, installation, mex

I have followed the wiki steps to install [mexopencv](https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv/wiki/Installation-%28Linux%2C-MATLAB%2C-OpenCV-3%29), but I get the following error:

```
$ make MATLABDIR=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a WITH_CONTRIB=true all contrib    

/tmp/mex_17713079591682_20541/Net_.o: In function `mexFunction':
    Net_.cpp:(.text+0x10dd): undefined reference to `cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_v3::Net::Net()'
    Net_.cpp:(.text+0x11ac): undefined reference to `cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_v3::readNetFromCaffe(cv::String const&, cv::String const&)'
    Net_.cpp:(.text+0x122a): undefined reference to `cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_v3::Net::~Net()'
    .. and so on
```

If I see what is to be built in opencv, the module dnn is present, which makes me wonder.

```
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.4.0 =====================================

--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core datasets dnn dpm face features2d flann freetype fuzzy hdf highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc line_descriptor ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python_bindings_generator reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking video videoio videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
--     Disabled:                    js python2 python3 world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cvv dnn_modern java matlab ovis sfm ts viz
```

Built modules:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv
-I/usr/local/include/opencv ..etc.. -lopencv_dnn .. etc
```

Current opencv version is:

```
$ pkg-config --modversion opencv
3.4.0
```

Question is; Is there a way to workaround/fix this, by i.e. disabling/unlinking dnn?

Or how do I actually compile the dnn file needed to get this reference to work?

{edit 1} file is actually compiled in:

```
$ ls /usr/local/include/opencv2/
...
bioinspired      dnn             fuzzy         imgproc              optflow               saliency      superres              videoio          xphoto.hpp
bioinspired.hpp  dnn.hpp         fuzzy.hpp     imgproc.hpp   
...
```

{edit 2} Unlinking -lopencv_dnn in the mexopencv Makefile by adding:

```
CV_LDFLAGS := $(filter-out -lopencv_dnn,$(CV_LDFLAGS))
```

is not an option, as still compilation fails on undefined reference to cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_v3. So I guess i'll need a fix for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to my problem. Cause was blindly following [mexopencv](https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv/wiki/Installation-%28Linux%2C-MATLAB%2C-OpenCV-3%29) for the Opencv installation part. I had to use the following in the cmake step:

```
# build and compile opencv-3.4.0:
$ cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" \
    -DBUILD_DOCS=OFF \
    -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF \
    -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF \
    -DBUILD_JAVA=OFF \
    -DWITH_CUDA=OFF \
    -DWITH_CUBLAS:BOOL=OFF \
    -DWITH_CUFFT:BOOL=OFF \
    -DWITH_NVCUVID:BOOL=OFF \
    -DBUILD_opencv_cudaarithm:BOOL=OFF \
    -DBUILD_opencv_cudabgsegm:BOOL=OFF \
    -DBUILD_opencv_cudacodec:BOOL=OFF \
    -DBUILD_opencv_cudafeatures2d:BOOL=OFF \
    -DBUILD_opencv_cudafilters:BOOL=OFF \
    -DBUILD_opencv_cudaimgproc:BOOL=OFF \
    -DBUILD_opencv_cudalegacy:BOOL=OFF \
    -DBUILD_opencv_cudaobjdetect:BOOL=OFF \
    -DBUILD_opencv_cudaoptflow:BOOL=OFF \
    -DBUILD_opencv_cudastereo:BOOL=OFF \
    -DBUILD_opencv_cudawarping:BOOL=OFF \
    -DBUILD_opencv_cudev:BOOL=OFF \
    -DBUILD_opencv_java=OFF \
    -DBUILD_opencv_js=OFF \
    -DBUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \
    -DBUILD_opencv_python3=OFF \
    -DBUILD_opencv_ts=OFF \
    -DBUILD_opencv_world=OFF \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
    -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/cv/opencv_contrib-3.4.0/modules ~/cv/opencv-3.4.0
$ make -j8  # -j$(nproc)
$ sudo make install

# compile mexopencv = OK
$ make MATLABDIR=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a WITH_CONTRIB=true all contrib
```

main difference to wiki is to remove the following two lines from the cmake step:

```
-DWITH_MATLAB=OFF \
-DBUILD_opencv_matlab=OFF \
```